# Howto setup JTable growth from bottom to top

Tags: java, swing

I'm looking for a way to fill JTable from **bottom to top**, for example:

1 row:

```
[clean space]
row1
```

after adding 2nd row:

```
[clean space]
row2
row1
```

Looked at ComponentOrientation - seems it allows only **right-to-left** but not **bottom-to-up**

Also don't see any ways by using LookAndFill

Any ideas?

Comment: You could try to order your results in inverse order, then place them into your `JTable`, to put empty rows just add as many of them as you need befor your results already inverted. For better help sooner please post a [mcve] and don't forget to say how many rows do you want to be above, is it just one?

Comment: It looks impossible for me. You can try to redefine methods `JTable.getCellRect`, `JTable.rowAtPoint` and `JTable.columnAtPoint` but it's difficult. If you have luck, this will work without of changes in UI (chance is not higher than 5%), if not you will need to create your own LookAndFeel based on currently used UI.

Comment: thank you Frakcoll and Sergiy, there's a solution below, just if you're wondering

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, thank you guys!

It's pretty simple by extracting table header to BorderLayout.NORTH and adding table entries to BorderLayout.SOUTH. This allows to make table growing from bottom to top.

Table entries can further be reversed by entries decorator by this way.

Code snippet below:

```
    final MyTableModel model = new ReverseOrderModelDecorator(new MyTableModel());
    final JTable table = new JTable(model);
    JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    mainPanel.add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    mainPanel.add(table, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the behaviour you are looking for:

```
import java.awt.ScrollPane;
import java.util.Collections;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Skynet
 */
public class JTableReverseFill {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Runnable r = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("jtable-reverse"); 
                frame.setSize(200,200);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JTable jt = new JTable();
                MyReversedTableModel mtm = new MyReversedTableModel();
                mtm.addColumn("col1");
                mtm.addColumn("col2");

                for(Integer i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    mtm.addRow(new Object[]{"cell" + i.toString(), "cell" + i.toString() + i.toString()});
                }    

                jt.setModel(mtm);

                ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
                sp.add(jt);
                frame.add(sp);

                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        };

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }


    public static class MyReversedTableModel extends DefaultTableModel 
    {        
        public void reverse()
        {
            Collections.reverse(getDataVector());            
        }

        @Override
        public void addRow(Object[] rowData) {
            reverse();
            super.addRow(rowData);
            reverse();
        }
    }
}
```

You can also call `reverse()` outside of the model to save some cpu time.